# Как уменьшить ширину кнопки для Windows Phone 8.1?

Tags: c#, xaml, button, windows-phone-8

Мне нужно разместить в своем приложении квадратную кнопку, но уменьшить ширину меньше дефолтной не получается (увеличить можно). Это вообще реально сделать со стандартной Button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всегда можно полностью переопределить темплейт. Но для начала попробуйте установить свойство MinWidth=0